# GWT: Exception: This widget's parent does not implement HasWidgets, but it does

Tags: gwt, composite

I am trying to create a structure where I have this larger UI with small parts that I can swap in and out and you get to more detailed areas.  In essence I am making top level panels which hold smaller panels from other composites.  Right now I am getting this exception:

```
    13:50:51.479 [ERROR] [managementconsole] Uncaught exception escaped

com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: This widget's parent does not implement HasWidgets
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This widget's parent does not implement HasWidgets
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.removeFromParent(Widget.java:204)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.LayoutPanel.insert(LayoutPanel.java:188)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.LayoutPanel.add(LayoutPanel.java:134)
    at com.impulse.mc.client.pm.PolicyManager.Init(PolicyManager.java:58)
    at com.impulse.mc.client.ManagementConsole$1.onClick(ManagementConsole.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:56)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1351)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1307)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:279)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:242)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My top level class:

```
public class ManagementConsole implements EntryPoint
{
    private MCConstants constants = GWT.create(MCConstants.class);

    private final DockLayoutPanel dockLayoutPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    private final VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    private final HorizontalPanel menuBar1 = new HorizontalPanel();
    public final HorizontalPanel menuBar2 = new HorizontalPanel();
    public final HorizontalPanel menuBar3 = new HorizontalPanel();
    private final Button btnPolicyManager = new Button("#Policy Manager");
    public final LayoutPanel mainPanel = new LayoutPanel();
    private final AbsolutePanel absolutePanel = new AbsolutePanel();
    private final TextArea txtrSplashScreenPut = new TextArea();
    private PolicyManager PM = null;
    private final ManagementConsole MC = this;

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        ABManager.setFactory( (MyABFactory) GWT.create( MyABFactory.class ) );
        ServerUtil.initServer();

        RootLayoutPanel root = RootLayoutPanel.get();

        root.add(dockLayoutPanel);
        root.setWidgetLeftRight(dockLayoutPanel, 0.0, Unit.PX, 0.0, Unit.PX);
        root.setWidgetTopHeight(dockLayoutPanel, 0.0, Unit.PX, 512.0, Unit.PX);
        verticalPanel.setBorderWidth(1);

        dockLayoutPanel.addNorth(verticalPanel, 7.7);
        verticalPanel.setWidth("100%");
        menuBar1.setStyleName("MenuBarStyle");
        menuBar1.setBorderWidth(1);

        verticalPanel.add(menuBar1);
        menuBar1.setWidth("0px");
        menuBar1.setSpacing( 10 );

        btnPolicyManager.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler()
        {
            public void onClick( ClickEvent event )
            {
                if ( null == PM )
                {
                    PM = new PolicyManager();
                }

                PM.Init( MC );
            }
        } );
        btnPolicyManager.setText( constants.policyManagerButton() );

        menuBar1.add( btnPolicyManager );

        verticalPanel.add( menuBar2);
        menuBar2.setWidth("0px");


        verticalPanel.add(menuBar3);
        menuBar3.setWidth("0px");

        dockLayoutPanel.add(mainPanel);

        mainPanel.add(absolutePanel);
        mainPanel.setWidgetLeftWidth(absolutePanel, 276.0, Unit.PX, 383.0, Unit.PX);
        mainPanel.setWidgetTopHeight(absolutePanel, 95.0, Unit.PX, 186.0, Unit.PX);
        txtrSplashScreenPut.setReadOnly(true);
        txtrSplashScreenPut.setTextAlignment(TextBoxBase.ALIGN_CENTER);
        txtrSplashScreenPut.setText("Splash Screen\r\nPut a graphic or some other text here");

        absolutePanel.add(txtrSplashScreenPut, 113, 57);
    }
}
```

And the class that is causing the exception, in the Init method:

```
public class PolicyManager extends Composite
{
    ManagementConsole MC = null;
    private final DockLayoutPanel myRootPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    private final DockLayoutPanel sidePanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    private final DockLayoutPanel mainPanel = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    private final Label lblWelcomeToThe = new Label("Welcome to the Policy Manager");

    // Only put in basic things that do not need the MC in the constructor
    public PolicyManager()
    {

        initWidget(myRootPanel);
        setSize("961px", "412px");
        myRootPanel.setSize("100%", "412px");

        myRootPanel.addWest(sidePanel, 17.3);

        myRootPanel.add(mainPanel);

        mainPanel.add(lblWelcomeToThe);

    }

    public void Init( ManagementConsole mc )
    {
        MC = mc;
        mc.menuBar2.clear();
        mc.menuBar3.clear();
        mc.mainPanel.clear();

        // This line causes the exception
        mc.mainPanel.add( myRootPanel );


    }
}
```

I do not understand that because the clear method is specified in HasWidgets.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to follow your code as you use the same names in different class and then reference the field of the other class..

You initWidget of the composite and insert a dockLP(myRootPanel) and then insert another dockLP in that child. Then you insert the myRootPanel inside of a LayoutPanel but it has already been added to the composite PolicyManager via initWidget.

I would imagine if you cleaned this up a bit your stack trace could better point you to the problem. It looks like your PolicyManager doesn't need to be a Composite and doesn't need to initWidget. Just manipulate existing panels. However, you could probably clean up the organization further.

java.lang.IllegalStateException - if this widget's parent does not support removal (e.g. Composite)

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#removeFromParent()

------------old---------

Might be a problem with standards mode

LayoutPanel - "This widget will only work in standards mode, which requires that the HTML page in which it is run have an explicit  declaration."?

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html

If not, Can you provide the full trace?

---

Comment: Ok, I updated with the full trace.  yes it is in standards mode.  It is using the normal html page when you create a GWT application which has that DOCTYPE declaration in it.

Comment: I did find if I change: " mc.mainPanel.add( myRootPanel );" to " mc.mainPanel.add( this );" it works, but I do not know why.

Comment: Probably because 'this' is the Composite which was initWidget(myRootPanel). Before you were adding myRootPanel twice

Comment: But I wasn't adding it twice, just once?  Or do you mean I added it to my composite, so it was "spoken for" and then I tried to add it to the other panel? I didn't know what InitWidget did exactly.

Comment: @AshtonThomas is almost certainly right - that bit about changing myRootPanel to this is the hint. The myRootPanel object's parent is 'this' at that point (since you called initWidget - assigning it to a new parent makes no sense (and the old parent, the composite, this, doesn't implement HasWidgets, like the error says).